# secret key not set in flask session, using the Flask-Session extension

Tags: python, session, flask

Right now I am using a flask 3rd party library [Flask-Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I am having no luck getting a session working.

When I connect to my site, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was
> set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and
> secret.

Below is my server code.

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.session import Session

SESSION_TYPE = 'memcache'
    
app = Flask(__name__)
sess = Session()

nextId = 0

def verifySessionId():
    global nextId

    if not 'userId' in session:
        session['userId'] = nextId
        nextId += 1
        sessionId = session['userId']
        print ("set userid[" + str(session['userId']) + "]")
    else:
        print ("using already set userid[" + str(session['userId']) + "]")
    sessionId = session.get('userId', None)
    return sessionId

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    userId = verifySessionId()
    print("User id[" + str(userId) + "]")
    return str(userId)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'

    sess.init_app(app)

    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

As you can see, I do set the app secret key. What am I doing wrong?

Are there other session options?

Other info:
Running Python 2.7 on Linux Mint

Full paste:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/session/sessiontest.py", line 27, in hello
    userId = verifySessionId()
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/session/sessiontest.py", line 16, in verifySessionId
    session['userId'] = nextId
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 341, in __setitem__
    self._get_current_object()[key] = value
  File "/home/sean/code/misc/hangman/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 126, in _fail
    raise RuntimeError('the session is unavailable because no secret '
RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

In your case the exception is raised by the `NullSessionInterface` session implementation, which is the *default session type* when you use Flask-Session. That's because you don't ever actually give the `SESSION_TYPE` configuration *to Flask*; it is *not enough* to set it as a global in your module. The [Flask-Session quickstart example code](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quickstart) does set a global, but then uses the current module as a configuration object by calling `app.config.from_object(__name__)`.

This default doesn't make much sense with Flask 0.10 or newer; `NullSession` may have made sense with Flask 0.8 or 0.9, but in current version the [`flask.session.NullSession` class](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.sessions.NullSession) is used as an error signal. In your case it gives you the wrong error message now.

Set the `SESSION_TYPE` configuration option to something else. Pick one of `redis`, `memcached`, `filesystem` or `mongodb`, and make sure to set it in `app.config` (directly or via the [various `Config.from_*` methods](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Config)).

For a quick test, setting it to `filesystem` is easiest; there is enough default configuration there to have that work without additional dependencies:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Quick test configuration. Please use proper Flask configuration options
    # in production settings, and use a separate file or environment variables
    # to manage the secret key!
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

    sess.init_app(app)

    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

If you see this error and you are **not** using Flask-Session, then something has gone wrong with setting the secret. If you are setting `app.config['SECRET_KEY']` or `app.secret_key` in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard like above and you get this error, then you are probably running your Flask app via a WSGI server that imports your Flask project *as a module*, and the `__name__ == "__main__"` block is never run.

It is always better to [manage configuration for Flask apps in a separate file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-files), anyway.

Comment: @martijin Pieters: where does this session variables gets stored? For example, if it is 'mongodb' where does the database that stores these session variables lives?

Comment: @iamai: that's documented the [Flask-Session *Configuration* section](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/#configuration); for mongodb, the default database name is `flask_session`, and the default collection is called `sessions`.

Comment: Something seems very wrong with this answer at least as of flask 1.1.2 (most likely earlier).  It states that you must set SESSION_TYPE and only lists options where the session is stored server-side.  But that is not [currently] correct.  If you succeed in setting a SECRET_KEY then the default session type will store the session in an encrypted cookie (not server side).  IE: you **don't need to** set SESSION_TYPE to get this working, you can set the SECRET_KEY as the error message suggests.

Comment: @PhilipCouling This answer is **specific to the `Flask-Session` extension**. You are thinking about base Flask. Yes, for the base Flask setup, `SECRET_KEY` is used to *cryptographically sign* the cookie (the cookie is *not encrypted*, the content can trivially be decoded, but not altered).

Comment: @PhilipCouling: the question makes this quite clear; the title contains *using the Flask-Session extension*, and starts with *Right now I am using a flask 3rd party library Flask-Session and I am having no luck getting a session working.*. If you came here looking for information on the base Flask setup for sessions, you'll need to refer to the [Flask API documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#sessions) and the [section on sessions in the Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions).

Comment: Just in case sombody is wondering about how to import Session the right way in 2022, it's: `from flask_session import Session` . Also warning for beginners: make your application reasonably secure from the start and use enviromental varioables: `app.secret_key = os.environ.get('YOUR_SECRET_KEY')` (ideally generate random hash and store it to your enviromental variables in your system).

Answer (score 78):

Set the secret key outside of `if __name__ == '__main__':`

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "super secret key"

@app.route("/")
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

When you start your app by running `flask run` the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block gets skipped. If you don't want to skip it, run with `python app.py`.

Comment: I'm running a flask app on an amazon ec2 apache2 Ubuntu server, using oauth2.0 to access google calendar information. This answer is the simple modification that made it work. Thank you!

Comment: This is an answer to a *different question*, one where the session type has been configured correctly or you are not using Flask-Session at all, but no secret has been set because a the WSGI server has loaded the module with import and not as the main script. **In production environments you want to store secrets outside of your codebase, in a separate configuration file anyway**.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'memcached'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super secret key'
sess = Session()
```

And remove your `app.secret_key` assignment at the bottom.

Comment: I gave this a shot, no luck, same error. I can update the posts code if you wish