# Flask RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set when using Flask-Session

Tags: python, heroku, flask

My heroku app will not allow me to register because of this error

```
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

however, i set the session key quite fine,

`run.py`:

```
from app import app, db, manager, sess
import os

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'reds209ndsldssdsljdsldsdsljdsldksdksdsdfsfsfsfis'
sess.init_app(app)
app.secret_key()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True;
    app.run()
    # manager.run()
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'memcached'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'redsfsfsfsfis'

from app import views, db
```

I already looked at [secret key not set in flask session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080872/secret-key-not-set-in-flask-session) but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to davidism i figured it out,

i had to put

`sess.init_app(app)`

after

`app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'redsfsfsfsfis'`