# Flask flash message cause Session is unavailable

Tags: flask

Use exact code from official docs:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            ..
            flash('File was successfully uploaded')
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Without `flash()` everything works ok. But when adding it causes error The session is unavailable because no secret. Below is a trace:

```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2019 10:16:21] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2019 10:17:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - [2019-02-18 10:17:23,999] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 2292, in wsgi_app
>     response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
>     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1718, in handle_user_exception
>     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
> line 35, in reraise
>     raise value   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
>     rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1799, in dispatch_request
>     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/app.py", line 39, in upload_file
>     flash('No file part')   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py",
> line 410, in flash
>     session['_flashes'] = flashes   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 350, in __setitem__
>     self._get_current_object()[key] = value   File "/home/dvperv/PycharmProjects/astros/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py",
> line 101, in _fail
>     raise RuntimeError('The session is unavailable because no secret ' RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was
> set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and
> secret.
> 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2019 10:17:24] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have read several posts about this error, but they all relates to a Flask-Session extension, **I do not use it**.

I also tried to add `app.secret_key = 'super secret key'` in the application, w/o success.

Shall I use Flask Session and make appropriate configuration or there is a way of just using plain Flask flash() which somehow works with sessions itself behind the scene.

App config:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = ..
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ..

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [secret key not set in flask session, using the Flask-Session extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080872/secret-key-not-set-in-flask-session-using-the-flask-session-extension)

Comment: I am not using this extension, as I said in my question

Comment: @Dmitry Did you try to set secret key using `config`(not app property)? `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ...`

Comment: No, as I believe, they should work identically. Shall I try?

Comment: @Dmitry yes they should work identically. anyway you need to find why setting do not work. Do you use 1 config? Does the problem repeat locally?

Comment: Actually I am new to Flask and Python and my app is extremely simple. I have the only configuration I showed in the question. App is run locally. And problem is reproducible at each run.

Comment: Both app.config[..] and app.secret_key works now. Seems that code was somehow cached and changes in the code did not reflect in the app.

Answer (score 1):

It's being stated very clearly in the stack trace that the secret key is not set. Be sure to set the secret key at the right place, for instance here:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'asrtarstaursdlarsn'

UPLOAD_FOLDER = ..
```

Answer (score 1):

The attached trace indicates that you have not added a secret key. May be you added the secret key later but the application was not synced with updated code.

I am sharing a basic example of using plain flash message in Flask.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super secret'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash("Flashing a dummy message")
    return render_template("flash_example.html")

@app.route('/another')
def show_page_without_flash():
    return render_template("flash_example.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`flash_example.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Flash example</title></head>
    <body>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <p>Dummy paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Route with a flash message(/):

[image: flash message example]

Route without a flash message(/another):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'anystringthatyoulike'
```

add a secret key