# Flask Problem: RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, secret-key, flask-session

So I was using flask_login for my login system on my mac, and I seem to have run into a problem. When I ran the code, it says I have not set my secret key even if I had done so.

My code was:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_session import Session
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user,logout_user, login_required, current_user
from models.model import *
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "<Some secret key>"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = '<Some Uri>'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)
Session(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'index'
login_manager.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return render_template("home.html")
    return render_template("login.html", tip="You have to log in first.")

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def verif():
    """ Gets name and password from form  """
    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    """ Checks user and password. """

    userpassCheck = User.query.filter(and_(User.username == username, User.password == password)).first()
    if not userpassCheck:
        return render_template("index.html", tip="Incorrect Username or Password.")

    login_user(userpassCheck)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

The whole error traceback was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/application.py", line 54, in verif
    login_user(userpassCheck)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 170, in login_user
    session['_user_id'] = user_id
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 350, in __setitem__
    self._get_current_object()[key] = value
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/Project1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 103, in _fail
    "The session is unavailable because no secret "
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

My expectations for the code was for it to be completely able to run. I haven't included the two HTML files because I think it is not related. I can add it if you think it is.

Using:
Python 3.7.7;
Flask 1.1.2;

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080996/6660373

Comment: I tried using ```app.config["SECRET_KEY"]```, but that doesn't work too. Same problem

Comment: @Keung : Try giving these properties :


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "<some key>"
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT']= False

Comment: Oh thanks! it works. Seems like I left out the SESSION_TYPE item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Harmandeep Kalsi said in the comments, I added `app.config['SESSION_TYPE']` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that is still getting an error after the other answers, if you're using the format `app.confing['<string>']` make sure that you include the underscore between "SECRET" and "KEY".

That ended up being my issue, but it results in the same error code so searching for it lead me here. So, I thought I'd provide my solution to anyone that comes across this in the future.

So what worked for me was switching:

```
app.config['SECRET KEY']
```

with:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY']
```